# How to return array from XLL function

Tags: c++, xll

I am new in writing XLL, Anyone knows how to return a 6x1 array to Excel ?

The following is my function (some codes came from other post):

```
__declspec(dllexport) LPXLOPER12  WINAPI GetArr(char* arg1, char* arg2)
{
   vector<double> arr = functionReturnVector;

   XLOPER12 list;
   list.xltype = xltypeMulti | xlbitDLLFree;
   list.val.array.lparray = new XLOPER12[6];
   list.val.array.rows = 6;
   list.val.array.columns = 1;
   for(int i = 0; i < 6; ++i) {
      list.val.array.lparray[i] = arr[i]; // error: IntelliSense: no operator "=" matches these operands
   }
return &list;
}
```

[2013-02-23]
Currently I read the codes from [XLL RETURN ARRAY](http://www.excelforum.com/excel-programming-vba-macros/525375-returning-arrays-from-custom-worksheet-functions-in-xll-files.html) and review my code, it can compile but returns 0 ...

```
__declspec(dllexport) LPXLOPER12 WINAPI GetArr(void)
{   
XLOPER xlArray, xlValues[2];

xlValues[0].xltype = xltypeNum;
xlValues[1].xltype = xltypeNum;
xlValues[0].val.num = 11;
xlValues[1].val.num = 17;

xlArray.xltype = xltypeMulti|xlbitDLLFree;
xlArray.val.array.rows = 1;
xlArray.val.array.columns = 2;
xlArray.val.array.lparray = &xlValues;

return &xlArray;
}
```

Comment: i dont know anything about xll, but "list" is a local variable first of all. you cant return pointers to local variables. second arr[i] has type <double>, when list.val.array.lparray[i] has <XLOPER12> type (you just did new XLOPER12[6] few lines before).

Comment: Possibly a duplicate question - [See here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14301998/how-to-return-an-array-from-an-xll-udf

Comment: Yes I have read this post, but the code still doesnt work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can print an 1X2 array in Excel worksheet now, the following is my code.

**use Func signature type U

1.select one row and two columns

2.Type command =GetArray() in first cell

3.Ctrl + shift + enter

```
 __declspec(dllexport) LPXLOPER12 WINAPI GetArray(void)
{
    static XLOPER12 xlArray;
    XLOPER12 xlValues[2];
    xlValues[0].xltype = xltypeNum;
    xlValues[1].xltype = xltypeNum;
    xlValues[0].val.num = 123;
    xlValues[1].val.num = 456;
    xlArray.xltype = xltypeMulti|xlbitDLLFree;
    xlArray.val.array.rows = 1;
    xlArray.val.array.columns = 2;
    xlArray.val.array.lparray = &xlValues;
    return (LPXLOPER12)&xlArray;
}
```

Comment: Trying you snippet throws me an a value of type `"XLOPER12 (*)[2]" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "xloper12 *` at compilation with visual studio community 2013. Any idea ?

Comment: It should be `xlArray.val.array.lparray = &xlValues[0];` and not `xlArray.val.array.lparray = &xlValues;`

Comment: Btw, how to do if I want to return an two-dimensional array ?

Comment: This answer just trigggers Undefined Behavior all over the place. 1- Object xlValues is destructed when you exit the scope of your function. you could make it static though. 2- Setting xlbitDLLFree will make Excel deallocate the array which was never allocated by the system in the first place

Answer (score 1):

Maybe http://xll.codplex.com can help you solve your problem, but as other people that are trying to help you, your code seems pretty far from shore.

On ne découvre pas de terre nouvelle sans consentir à perdre de vue, d'abord et longtemps, tout rivage.

Just kidding. Maybe that will work for you.